# Numbers lost sign in .NET 4.6, ODP.NET, EF6

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5, odp.net, linqpad

I noticed that numbers I retrieved from an Oracle database with .Net 4.6, IQToolkit, and LinqPad5 lost their signs.  The query:

SQL:

```
select -3 from SomeTable where rownum <= 1
```

Linq:

```
(from iVal in SomeTables select new { Value = -3}).Take(1)
```

Scenario 1: In LinqPad5, with IQToolKit.Data.OracleClient 0.17.1, Devart.Data.Oracle 7.9.333, and .Net 4.6, both queries returned **3** (loss of sign).

Scenario 2: In LinqPad4, with IQToolKit.Data.OracleClient 0.17.1, Devart.Data.Oracle 7.9.333, and .Net 4.0, both queries returned **-3** (correct value).

Scenario 3: In Visual Studio 2013, with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.121.2, 6.121.2, EntityFramework 6.0, and .Net 4.5, the Linq query returned **3** (loss of sign).

All of above are run on a machine with Oracle Home client 11g and 12 installed.

On a separate machine, which also has both versions of the Oracle client, but only .net 4.0 is installed, the second scenario returned **-3**.

Can anyone deduce which piece of technology is causing the issue here?  I feel it points to .Net >= 4.5, but that idea sounds ridiculous.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Not the client, but the database.

Comment: Oracle server version 11.

Comment: And now that you've removed the `TOP` from your query, are you still getting the same problematic results? It would help if you'd edit your question, include the DDL of `SOMETABLE` and some test data.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes same result, TOP was SQL Server syntax.  I switched back to Oracle syntax.  I am selecting a constant from SomeTable, so the structure and the data of SomeTable doesn't come into play by design.

Comment: Is it a 64bit application? Can you try disabling RyuJit? (https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/docs/testing-with-ryujit.md#disable-ryujit)

Comment: I posted the issue on Oracle and Devart.  It has to do with the newest version of the .net framework and the Roslyn compiler.  I don't fully understand the details, but Devart fixed the problem.